# Validating Non Empty String for Styled Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I'm currently using the `styled-components` library in React for a `Form`. The component sends a `POST` request when a "Create" `Button` is clicked.

```
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledInput = styled(Form.Control)`
  padding: 2px 5px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 50px;
`;

function Builder() {

const [name, setName] = useState("");

 return (
    <GridWrapper>
      <h1>Builder</h1>
      <Form>
        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group controlId="name" bssize="large">
            <Form.Label>Probet Name</Form.Label>
            <StyledInput
              size="sm"
              required
              value={name}
              type="String"
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              className="smaller-input"
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
      </Form>
      <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Create
      </Button>
    </GridWrapper>
  );
}

My question is, I have passed the `required` prop into the `StyledInput` component, yet when I click on the "Create" `Button` it still sends through an empty String. Is there a quick way to validate this using `styled-components` or do I have to write something myself in the `handleSubmit` function?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Button` of `type="submit"` inside of the `Form` so the validation occurs. As for the submission, you can handle this using the `onSubmit` prop of `Form` instead of handling it on the click of the `Button`

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Row>
    <Form.Group controlId="name" bssize="large">
      <Form.Label>Probet Name</Form.Label>
      <StyledInput
        size="sm"
        required
        value={name}
        type="String"
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        className="smaller-input"
      />
    </Form.Group>
  </Form.Row>
  <Button type="submit">
    Create
  </Button>
</Form>
```

Note that if you are performing additional logic before submission or are performing XHR instead of redirection, you can opt to use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event object when handling the submission

Example:

```
<Form onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //some logic
}
```

---

Lastly, you are using hooks (i.e., `const [name, setName] = useState("")`) outside of a Functional Component's body. This will cause errors - I suggest to move it inside of `function Builder`

Comment: Yes apologies, I made a mistake copying and pasting. The hooks are in the function now.